# Getting a "Bad Request" Message for signup and sign in

Tags: javascript, bad-request

The sign up route for the website I'm working on isn't working fine. I get this once I click on sign up it says "Bad Request Error and this once i click on sign in it says " Cannot Post"

Here the sign up route code

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res){

  User.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/signup");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("home");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the sign in code

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res){

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/home");
      });
    }
  });

});
```

PS. It seems to register because when I create users they appear in the database [image: Image of datastore showing added users]

Comment: Please add code/error messages as text to the question, rather than as images.

Comment: Please include your code as Text and not as Pictures. See: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please also include examples of the requests being made

Comment: you are getting `Cannot POST /` because you don't have a `POST` on route `/`. As per images, you have post routes for `/sigin` and `/signup`.

Comment: You need to provide the form where you send these requests. Otherwise, it's hard to predict what you might have there.

Comment: @Himanshu Singh I'm not sure what you mean by POST on route.

Comment: I mean to say that, you are trying to do `POST` request on `/` which is not configured in your backend according to the error according to the image you have added previously.

Comment: `app.post` sets up an endpoint using the POST method, you don't appear to have one for `/`, you have shown us them for `/signup` and `/login`. perhaps the login form is posting the form to the wrong url

Comment: I do have a `/ ` here `app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home")
});`

Comment: Yep, and it only supports GET requests, but it looks like your login form is POST'ing the data to `/` which is why you get the "Cannot Post" error

Comment: I'm also guessing that signup form works as expected but the redirect (`res.redirect("/home")`) causes the bad request. Note, this is a guess as you haven't shown us the network requests that the browser is making.

Comment: Here is the sign in form `<form action="/homeafterauthentication" class="form-signin" method="POST">` `<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control bottom1" placeholder="Password" required>`

Comment: Here is the post code `app.post("/homeafterauthentication", function(req, res){
  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.render("homeafterauthentication");
      });
    }
  });

});
`

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the code there? and delete these comments